# python selenium check if javascript alert/pupup is open

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, selenium

I have this html code :

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
alert("Hello world");
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Whit python selenium i need to check if this hello popup is open, problem is this popup have every time different text content, how can i check if this popup is open or not ?

My start code :

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://google.com/test.html")
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoAlertPresentException
from selenium import webdriver
import unittest

class Foo(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.selenium = webdriver.Firefox()
        self.selenium.maximize_window()

    def is_alert_visible(self):
        alert = self.selenium.switch_to_alert()
        try:
            return alert.text
        except (NoAlertPresentException,):
            return False

    def test_page(self):
        self.selenium.get('url')
        self.assertTrue(self.is_alert_visible())

    def tearDown(self):
        self.selenium.quit()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

or you can use `webdriverwait` to wait specific amount of time for that alert and raise `TimeoutException` if it doesn't show up

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait as Wait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException

def is_alert_visible(self):
    try:
        alert = Wait(self.selenium, 5).until(EC.alert_is_present())
        return alert.text
    except (TimeoutException,):
        return False

def test_page(self):
    self.selenium.get('url')
    self.assertTrue(self.is_alert_visible())
```